# cant understand meaning of following lines in haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
#{@current_user.allowed_events.size}

#{@current_user.batch_mates.size}

link_to "<span>#{@current_user.related_colleges.size}</span>Colleges".html_safe
```

in above lines what are these allowed_events.size,related_colleges.size?
are these builtin functions?

Comment: I don't know much about haml but that looks like a variable or a method call to return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `allowed_events` and `batch_mates` are either an association or method on the `User` model (assuming that's what `@current_user` references). Take a look in `apps/models/user.rb` and see if you find anything there.

Those methods are likely returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is sort like a class wrapper around an array of models, typically returned from a database search. Anyway, the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class has a [`size`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-size) method which is very similar to `length` or [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count).

So it's most likely just spitting out the number of allowed events and batch mates that belong to the current user.

As for the `#{}` that's just triggering [Ruby interpolation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_). You could also do it this way:

```
= @current_user.allowed_events.size

= @current_user.batch_mates.size
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, current_user is an object of User model. related_colleges and allowed_events could be associations/method/name scope in use model, you need to see your User.rb file in model to get it. I think these are associations (likely has_many) where size is the method to get the count of associated objects